# AngularJS object is null when passed to REST web service

Tags: web-services, angularjs, rest

Angular newbie and I have had no luck getting to the bottom of this one.  I am trying to send an update call to my RESTful web service.  I am passing and int and an object.  When debugging back at the web service, the int comes in fine, however the object always come is as NULL.  Debugging before the call is made shows that the object has a value.  Why am I getting NULL for my object in the web service?

I have tried making the call from a factory as well as the save function. Both are null when the web service is called.

***app.js***

```
TournamentDirectorApp.factory('tournamentFactory', function () {
    return {
        addUserToTournament: function (id, tourney, user, Tournament) {
            tourney.Users.push(user)
            var response = Tournament.update({ id: id }, { tourney: tourney })
            return tourney;
        }
    };
 });

$scope.save = function () {
    var updatedTournament = tournamentFactory.addUserToTournament(id, selectedTourney, $scope.selectedUser, Tournament);

    Tournament.update({ id: id }, { tournament: updatedTournament }, function () {
        $location.path('/')
    });

};
```

***web service***

```
    public HttpResponseMessage PutTournament(int id, Tournament tournament)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid && id == tournament.TournamentId)
        {
            db.Entry(tournament).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        }
        else
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
    }
```

*** tournament object ***

```
public class Tournament
{
    public int TournamentId { get; set; }
    public string Director { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Classification> Classifications { get; set; }

    public virtual List<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

*** app.js (routing for the update) ***

```
TournamentDirectorApp.factory('Tournament', function ($resource) {
return $resource('/api/tournament/:id', { id: '@id' }, {update: { method: 'PUT' }});
```

});

Comment: What does the code of Tournament.update look like?

Comment: That is the call that is getting routed to my web service PutTournament method.

Comment: What does the code look like?  Are you using some sort of library to make the call?  My instinct is that you should be passing a single object, like this: {id: id, tournament: updatedTournament}, instead of two parameters each of which contains an object with one property, but I'd have to see more code.

Comment: Check above.  I have added the route for the update to the PutTournament web method.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the "update" example in the angular docs, I think the problem is that you should just send just the updatedTournament with the update request, not an object wrapping your changed object.  Try:

```
Tournament.update({ id: id }, updatedTournament, function () {
        $location.path('/') })
```

in your save function.

Comment: Yes, that did it.  Removed the object wrapping of updatedTournament object.  Thanks Geoff!